# How to ping in python to Source address to use

Tags: python-3.x, ping

Now i want to ping in python like that:

> ping www.google.com -S 8.8.8.8
>   this works in cmd so is there a way to do that in python ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Pyping](https://pypi.org/project/pyping/) module can do this.It can be installed using `pip`

`pip install pyping`

It is really easy to use.

```py
import pyping

reply = pyping.ping('www.google.com')

if reply.ret_code == 0:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failed with {}".format(reply.ret_code))
```

PS : You must run the script as **Administrator** in windows since we are sending a ICMP message.

EDIT 1:
Try this script

```py
import os
os.system('cmd /k "ping www.google.com -S 8.8.8.8"')
```

Comment: It is not that i want my question is how to ping in this way: ping www.google.com -S 8.8.8.8

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the question i have edited the answer please try it out and let me know the result